# CreateFeatureclass_management Not Displaying in Map - Null Geometry

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, feature-class, null-geometry

I have two feature classes that share a common ID field. I wrote a script to create a new feature class that contains the records in the first FC that are not in the second FC.

It works, in that it creates a feature class with the records that are different, however the new feature class will not display. I have tried running Check Geometry on it, and the "Problem" says "null geometry" for every record in the new FC. It has a spatial reference, but the extent is blank.

I can get the newFC to display by joining it to the first FC and exporting it, but that seems like a workaround that I could avoid.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
import arcpy  

def createMatchingFieldList(fc1, fc2):  
    lst1 = [fld.name for fld in arcpy.ListFields(fc1)]  
    lst2 = [fld.name for fld in arcpy.ListFields(fc2)]  
    return list(set(lst1) & set(lst2))  

def createWhereClause(fc, fld_name, value):  
    if len(arcpy.ListFields(fc, fld_name)) == 1:  
        fld = arcpy.ListFields(fc, fld_name)[0]  
        if fld.type == "String":
            where = "{0} = '{1}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fld_name), value)  
        else:
            where = "{0} = {1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fld_name), value)  
    return where

def getPrimaryFieldValues(fc, field):  
    return [r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [field])]

def getSelectCursor(fc, flds, whereClause):
    return arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, flds, whereClause)  

def diff(a, b):  
    return list(set(a) - set(b))

#Get Parameters 
#feature class 1
source1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#feature class 2
source2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
#new feature class location
my_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
#new feature class
new_fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)  
#Name of Key Field in feature class 1
fieldName1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
#Name of Key Field in feature class 2
fieldName2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
#Spatial Reference
spatial_reference = arcpy.Describe(source1).spatialReference

#my attempt to get the new_fc to display
#define coordinate system
#arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1983 UTM Zone 15N")

# create empty feature class
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(my_path, new_fc,"", source1,"","", spatial_reference)

# create a list of field names which are in both featureclasses  
flds = createMatchingFieldList(source1, source2)

source1Values = getPrimaryFieldValues(source1, fieldName1)  
source2Values = getPrimaryFieldValues(source2, fieldName2)  

additions = diff(source1Values, source2Values)  

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(new_fc, flds) as insertCursor:  
    for a in additions:
        where = createWhereClause(source1, fieldName1, a)  
        insertRows = getSelectCursor(source1, flds, where)  
        for r in insertRows:  
            insertCursor.insertRow(r)
```

[image: Tool Parameters]

Comment: Is Shape in list of matching fields?

Comment: I would verify what `createMatchingFieldList` and `createWhereClause` are returning to be sure what you think is really happening?